# Working out age of a person from input & date objects

Tags: javascript, date

After getting the users input of their birth information, I want to convert their age to milliseconds and then subtract it from the current date to return their age, how do I do this properly?:

```
var birthYear = parseInt(prompt ('Enter your birth year:'));
var birthMonth = prompt ('Enter the name of the month of birth:');
var birthDay = parseInt(prompt ('Enter your day of birth as an integer:'));
var milliDay = 1000*60*60*24; //Milliseconds in a day
monthAbb = 'janfebmaraprmayjunjulaugsepoctnovdec';
chineseZod = 12;
zodCycle = 1924; //Chinese Zodiac Cycle
var monthArr = new Array(11);


monthArr [0] = "jan";
monthArr [1] = "feb";
monthArr [2] = "mar";
monthArr [3] = "apr";
monthArr [4] = "may";
monthArr [5] = "jun";
monthArr [6] = "jul";
monthArr [7] = "aug";
monthArr [8] = "sep";
monthArr [9] = "oct";
monthArr [10] = "nov";
monthArr [11] = "dec";

var monthNum = monthAbb.indexOf(birthMonth.slice(0, 3).toLowerCase()) / 3; 
alert(monthNum);
var d = new Date (birthYear, monthNum, birthDay);
alert(d);
```

Comment: new Date(newDate().getTime() - new Date (birthYear, monthNum, birthDay).getTime()).getTime() / 1000 / 3600 / 24 / 365.25;

Comment: If you calculate the age in milliseconds, you can't reliably display the age in any larger unit than days. Any larger time unit (e.g. years) varies in length, so you have to calculate the age in time units from the birth date, not only the difference between the birth date and todays date.

Comment: -Use the getTime() member function to get a Date object's time in milliseconds
-Deduct the user's date of birth time from the current time
That's what I'm supposed to do^ Thx.

Comment: @Chera—you don't need to use `getTime()`, just subtract one date object from another, the result will be the difference in ms.

Answer (score 0):

```
var today=new Date();
var millisec=today.getTime();
alert(millisec);
```

this will return you time in millisecond.
for example to calculate age:-

```
    var dt1 = new Date();
    var age = (dt1.getTime() - d.getTime()) / (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var d0 = new Date(2012, 0, 1); // 1 January 2012
var d1 = new Date(2012, 2, 31); // 31 March 2012

alert(d1 - d0); // 7776000000 which is the difference in milliseconds
```

The above may be affected by changes in or out of daylight saving. To avoid that, use UTC:

```
var d0 = Date.UTC(2012, 0, 1); // 1 January 2012
var d1 = Date.UTC(2012, 2, 31); // 31 March 2012

alert(d1 - d0); // 7776000000 which is the difference in milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Leap years need to be accounted for if you want, say, an eighteen year old to wait the 2 or 3 days difference until his actual birthday.

You can estimate a year as **365.25***24*60*60*1000, and often will be correct.

```
function agefromYMD(y, m, d){
    var years, months, days, dA, nA,
    dob= new Date(y, m-1, d),
    now= new Date();
    now.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    return Math.floor((now-dob)/(365.25*24*60*60*1000));
}
```

or you can look at the dates, months and fullYears.

```
function agefromYMD(y, m, d){
    var years, months, days, dA, nA,
    dob= new Date(y, m-1, d),
    now= new Date();
    now.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    dA= [dob.getUTCFullYear(), dob.getUTCMonth(), dob.getUTCDate()];
    nA= [now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate()];
    years= nA[0]-dA[0];
    months= nA[1]-dA[1];
    days= nA[2]-dA[2];
    if(months<=0 && days<0)--months;
    if(months<0)--years;
    return years;
}
```

agefromYMD(1984,2,26)